# Random Forest - trying to deal with oversampling by resampling data but getting error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

My train/validation scores are around 1 but my test scores are around 0.5 - I'm trying to resample but making no progress - I keep getting this error.

I'm trying to classify by class 0 or 1 but getting the issue above - I tried to use KFold but am struggling to implement this and now trying to oversample but getting this error. I belive I have implemeted my classifier correctly - I've removed duplicates and quite a few features of the dataset with low correlation

Also could someone help me under Kfold - with Kfold do you not need to apply 3 splits? If not how to i visualise the confusion matrix of the test data after Kfold

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_left, y_train, y_left = train_test_split(x,y, train_size=0.8,shuffle=True)
x_validation, x_test, y_validation, y_test = train_test_split(x_left,y_left, test_size=0.5,shuffle=True)

ros = RandomOverSampler(random_state=0)
x_resampled, y_resampled = ros.fit_resample(x_train, y_train)
print(x_resampled.shape)
print(y_resampled.shape)
(440308, 15)
(440308,)

Training the Data
Random Forest
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

model = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, min_samples_leaf=10, n_estimators=50,
                       n_jobs=-1, random_state=42)

model.fit(x_train, y_train)
prediction = model.predict(x_test)


accuracy_test = (accuracy_score(y_test, prediction))
precision_test = precision_score(y_test, prediction)
recall_test = recall_score(y_test, prediction)
f1_test = f1_score(y_test,prediction)

print(accuracy_test)
print(precision_test)
print(recall_test)
print(f1_test)
0.9993107701236986
0.8809523809523809
0.7254901960784313
0.7956989247311828
confusion_matrix_test = confusion_matrix(y_test, prediction)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix_test, xticklabels=x_tick, yticklabels=y_tick, fmt = "1", annot=True)
plt.show()

accuracy_validation = (accuracy_score(y_validation, prediction))
precision_validation = precision_score(y_validation, prediction)
recall_validation = recall_score(y_validation, prediction)
f1_validation = f1_score(y_validation, prediction)

print(accuracy_validation)
print(precision_validation)
print(recall_validation)
print(f1_validation)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/gf/883_hjm142zbdy0b5f33lct80000gn/T/ipykernel_1852/832904656.py in <module>
----> 1 accuracy_validation = (accuracy_score(y_validation, prediction))
      2 
      3 #Precision = True Positives / (True Positives + False Positives)
      4 precision_validation = precision_score(y_validation, prediction)
      5 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize, sample_weight)
    209 
    210     # Compute accuracy for each possible representation
--> 211     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    212     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    213     if y_type.startswith("multilabel"):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     82     y_pred : array or indicator matrix
     83     """
---> 84     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
     85     type_true = type_of_target(y_true)
     86     type_pred = type_of_target(y_pred)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    330     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    331     if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 332         raise ValueError(
    333             "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: %r"
    334             % [int(l) for l in lengths]

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [27566, 27567]
```

Comment: Add `prediction = model.predict(x_validation)` before the error line.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for leaving a comment. Surely I cannot predict the test data - does this not mean that the data is no longer unseen?Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "cannot predict the test data". The problem in your original question is that you use the prediction of `x_test` to compare with `y_validation`. That's why it's wrong.